# Returning a value when clicking a button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a simple text box and want to take the text from it when i click on a button, but for some reason it doesn't work. I tried using a global variable but it still doesn't work.
Here is what i have written sofar:

```
t = Text(r, height=20, width=40)
t.pack()

def myClick():
    myLabel= Label(r,text= "Sent!")
    global input
    input = t.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    myLabel.pack()




myButton = Button(r, text="Send ", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()
print(input)
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean *"it doesn't work"*?  Do you mean that the output of `print(input)` is not what you expect?

Comment: At the point where you have `print(input)`, the Button has just been created about a millisecond ago - there has been no opportunity for the user to click it yet.  The *one* place in your code where the Button is known to have been clicked is inside `myClick()` - anything you want to do in response to the click has to go in there.

Comment: @jasonharper Does this mean that when i click the input variable has changed to the text i have written in the text box.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using too many arguments in the  `.get()` and the widget type has to be `Entry` and you really should [define](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types) your variable before everything else. Here is my suggestion for your code:

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()

t = Entry(r, width=40)
t.pack()

def myClick():
    global input
    input = t.get()
    myLabel= Label(r,text= input)
    myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(r, text="Send ", command=myClick)
myButton.pack()
print(input)
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: This has exactly the same problem as the original code; `input` gets used before there has been any possibility of the Button being clicked.  (And the two parameters to `.get()` are in fact correct when used with a Text.)